# Error in loading node by nid

Tags: nodes

I try to load a node at a view using the node_load() function which takes an integer argument. I take the node id by `$nid=$fields['nid']->content;` and I try to load the node by calling `node_load($nid)` but it fails. After experimenting i figured out that $nid is String instead of integer so I try to cast to an int but it returns me 0. Can anybody help me?

```
$nid=$fields['nid']->content;

print gettype($nid);

print $nid;
print intval($nid);
print (int) $nid;
```

Output:

string 3 0 0

I am within a view and I want to load many node as is to put them in a bootstrap tab where it when you click the node name the node will be shown above it.

Comment: I just tried: node_load(60459) and node_load('60459') and I didn't get an error.  What is the error you get? Are you sure the node exists?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It's like I execute node_load(0) and nothing is returned. The node does exists. If I execute node_load(3) it works fine.

Comment: The way you are trying to get the node id doesn't look right ($nid=$fields['nid']->content;) but I can be wrong.

Comment: This is a view I am currently in with a field node. It works fine as it should.

Comment: You don't need to convert to an integer anyways so you can just do a node_load($nid).

Comment: Where are you putting this code and what are you trying to do?  I have a feeling that there might be a better way to just do this within views.

Comment: I am within a view and I want to load many node as  is to put them in a bootstrap tab where it when you click the node name the node will be shown above it.

Comment: It sounds like you want to change your view from Fields to either Content or Rendered Entity, depending on what modules you have.  And then set a display mode on your content to allow that processing.